# Searchview using shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, searchview

Here is the link to implement a searchview in action bar for android.
http://www.android86.com/android-advanced/action-bar-search-view/

according to the above example i've implemented action bar search view. Now once the user starts typing inside the search bar i want to provide him "suggestions". These suggestions should be available from the array list that i've retrieved via shared pref.
How should i implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show search suggestions from a `ArrayList` directly. You have to user a content provider. See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now what i'l be doing is use sqlite and use the content provider to populate the suggestions. Will get back once its done. :)